# Which table to act on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Say I have two tables xs and ys in the database; both xs, ys have two columns id, name, and several rows: where for both tables the first row has entries

```
id = 1, name = "John".
```

Now in rails,

```
X.find(1)
```

and

```
Y.find(1)
```

returns the same hash:

```
{id: 1, name: "John"}
```

Now both

```
X.find(1)
```

and

```
Y.find(1)
```

has method `destroy`, which should not be a standard ruby hash method. I had to make myself content with the idea that rails somehow provided these hashes with this method.

But how

```
{id: 1, name: "John"}.destroy
```

knows which of the tables xs, ys should have its first row destroyed?

Comment: Edit your question by adding the db details also, like which db are yiu using? sqlite, mysql, postgresql or any other?

Comment: "returns the same hash" - no, you are mistaken, it most certainly is not returning a __hash__. It is returning a model instance, which, through naming convention of its class, knows what table it belongs to.

Comment: @AakashGupta: the exact database should be irrelevant in this case. ActiveRecord is abstract enough to shield us from the actual backend.

Comment: I also thought the same thing but I have not worked on no sql dbs with rails. So I though no sql dbs might return Active Relation records as hash. But as you have specified this, I'm sure that in any case, the query must return AR Record which contains information capable enough to tell which table and model it belongs to. So, question is actually irrelevant containing false information.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But if X.find(1) isn't a hash, how come we can search in the key :name, as in X.find(1)[:name]?

Comment: @TonyMarshle: not only hashes respond to message `[]`. Many other things do. When you say `X.find(1).class`, what does it say? THAT is from where you should draw ideas about what things are, not a vague resemblance of the thing's api to an api of another thing.